# When should I generate html using RenderTreeBuilder instead Razor syntax

Tags: blazor

With Blazor we can generate the component's Html elements using Razor syntax or overriding `BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)`.

I've noticed that who writes libraries usually prefer to create a single .cs file per component defining the Html elements inside the *BuilderRenderTree* method. Instead, who writes a project prefer to create two files per component (Html in .razor and logic .cs) or a single .razor file (Html and logic in one place).

I've already read

- https://chrissainty.com/building-components-via-rendertreebuilder/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manual-rendertreebuilder-logic

So, my question is

> Why (and when) should I override BuilderRenderTree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general guide is that if you can do it using `.razor` syntax it's always easier to create, edit, read and maintain.

However there are some cases where it's not possible to do this. One example is a demo I did last year for dynamic components: I need to render a component but I only have the `System.Type` value - this allows me to render different components via code.

See [the relevant C# file](https://github.com/conficient/BlazorDynamicList/blob/master/BlazorDynamicList.Client/DynamicComponent.cs)

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, there are three main ways to author your components

- Using a single file (.razor extension) with two parts: The view part of the component which contains C#, Razor markup, including directives, etc. and Html markup, and the code part which is placed in @code blocks. This is the easiest way to code. This is also my preferred way. Everything is set at my sight.
- Others prefer to separate the file described above into two separate files: the first is dedicated to the view portion of the Razor component, and having a file extension .razor; the second part is the code portion of the view with the .razor.cs extension, currently you can define as a partial class. I find it hard to work with two related files.
- The third option is a single file with code to create the render tree by overriding the BuildRenderTree method. You are right that component author usually code in such a style, but there is no difference in the end result between this form of authering and the other two mentioned above, except that it is much more difficult to code like that: you have to learn a great deal; that is you must invest time learning how to do it, instead of letting the compiler do the work for you. But still worse, this method is prone to mistakes, and it is not recommended on daily basis. Good and elegant code should be simple and clear.   And as Blazor web developer one should stick to methods that enable him to write god code in the shortest span of time...

Hope this helps...